# Crop Image android to Corners

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello im have one layout to comments_logs allign right,Im using Aquery Android
My Xml LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_comments"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_comments"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_comments" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And My Class, image_url is my variable for image to url in my server:

```
String image_url="example_for_image_url_string"

int layout_id = R.layout.layout_comment_left;

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(layout_id, null, false);
                                AQuery aq = new AQuery(relativeLayout);
                                aq.id(R.id.image_comments).image(image_url);




 TextView message = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.message);
                            message.setText(message_json);
                            layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

Pleas,How to set a or convert my image in circle, i need croop a corner or radius

regards!

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378873/4224337

Comment: No is for my question , thanks but is no answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Im Solved this questions by :

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(relativeLayout);
ImageOptions options = new ImageOptions();

options.round = 105;

aq.id(R.id.image_comments).image(image_url,options);
```